# ExpressJs retry query after long time processing

Tags: node.js, express

We are having a weird problem with our Nodejs-Expressjs server. We are trying to perform a heavy query that takes 5-10 minutes to finish. The query works well, but for some reason after 2-4 minutes the server retry the query again.

We have traceability logging implanted and we see the query is performed twice with the same requested.

Does anyone have an idea of the possible reasons for this behavior?

```
,Request Morgan --> ,77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-**d59736a2f169,POST,undefined,/admin/cars/feed,undefined ms,@ Thu, 29 Apr 2021 07:02:25 GMT,127.0.0.1,from http://localhost:8085/,Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Mobile Safari/537.36,  Size= ,undefined,bytes,**

undefined
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:30  info : Receiving JWT payload {"sub":{"userId":"fc32df37-ee2b-44e3-a864-8b73ea31d1aa","roleId":2},"tokenId":"RReUCy7UD","type":0,"iat":1619675641}   
77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169
Your token is VALID
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:31  info : User data found in cache   
77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:32  debug : User "baaldev" authenticated   
77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:32  info : Validating POST:/cars/feed   
undefined
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:32  info : /admin/cars/feed request with data 
        filters=[{"carOwnerType":{"value":[{"value":"hideScrapped","label":"SEARCHCAR.FROM_SCRAPPED"}]}}]
        name=t
        platform=trovit   
undefined
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:33  info : User is authenticated to request    
undefined
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:62  debug : Getting cars   
77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:87  info : Executing (default): SELECT count(`CarsForSelling`.`carId`) AS `count` FROM `CarsForSelling` AS `CarsForSelling` LEFT OUTER JOIN `UserInformation` AS `OwnedCars` ON `CarsForSelling`.`userId` = `OwnedCars`.`userId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `BusinessInformation` AS `OwnedCars->BusinessInformation` ON `OwnedCars`.`userId` = `OwnedCars->BusinessInformation`.`userId` WHERE `CarsForSelling`.`status` > 0 AND `CarsForSelling`.`lockStatus` = '0' AND `CarsForSelling`.`validUntil` >= '2021-04-29 07:02:32';   
undefined

 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:29  http : HTTP log   
77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:29  info : 


**,Request Morgan --> ,77e53abf-272c-420d-9e82-d59736a2f169,POST,undefined,/admin/cars/feed,undefined ms,@ Thu, 29 Apr 2021 07:04:26 GMT,127.0.0.1,from http://localhost:8085/,Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Mobile Safari/537.36,  Size= ,undefined,bytes,**


undefined
 [LOGGER]  21-04-29 09:04:78  info : Executing (default): SELECT `CarsForSelling`.*, `CarImages`.`imageId` AS `CarImages.imageId`, `CarImages`.`carId` AS `CarImages.carId`, `CarImages`.`imageName` AS `CarImages.imageName`, `CarImages`.`imageUrl` AS `CarImages.imageUrl`, `CarImages`.`order` AS `CarImages.order`, `CarImages`.`imageSourceUrl` AS `CarImages.imageSourceUrl`, `CarImages`.`createdAt` AS
```

Comment: It probably a network issue. Could you please confirm does the TCP connection between your app and database still exist?

Comment: Hi @Pylo. Yes, it exits. In fact, the database query did finish when the query repeats.

Answer (score 0):

It is why we have `status code 202`

```js
function endPoint (req, res) {
  // code

  //Do not put a `return`
  res.sendStatus(202);

  // exec query
  const result = runQuery()

  return;

}
```

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 202 Accepted response status
> code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but
> the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not
> have started yet. The request might or might not eventually be acted
> upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>
> 202 is non-committal, meaning that there is no way for the HTTP to
> later send an asynchronous response indicating the outcome of
> processing the request. It is intended for cases where another process
> or server handles the request, or for batch processing.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Ernesto. I think that's not the case. Anyways, I added some logs. Check it out, please. Perhaps, you have other idea.